# From textbox to decimal value then into access database in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, textbox, decimal

I'm reading a decimal value from textbox1 and need to insert it to an decimal field in my database.

I having a trouble with "," and "." so first I'm replacing ","s with "." But unfortunately If I enter 1.34 in textbox, it becomes 134.00 in db.

```
string text = textBox1.Text;
text = text.Replace(",", ".");
decimal total = decimal.Parse(text);
```

how can I solve this issue?

Comment: This question has nothing at all to do with ms-access.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
CultureInfo en_us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
decimal value = Decimal.Parse(text, en_us);
```

Comment: when it was 1.6 in textbox value after replacing, after decimal.parse value is becoming 16

Comment: No CultureInfo. How can set this settings ?

Comment: This will fail on some languages. See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001075.html

Comment: Sorry but;

string text = textBox_BirimFiyat.Text;
                    
decimal birim_fiyat = decimal.Parse(text.Replace(",","."), new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR"));

still after parsing, 13.4 value becomes 134 :(

Comment: I can't understand where is the problem. 
decimal birim_fiyat = decimal.Parse(text, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us"));

while text is 13.45 birim_fiyat becomes 1345.00 as I set in my field in db.

Comment: hmm, can you inspect that value _before_ arrive on database?

Comment: so do we finish? I'm missing something?